Nuxt 2 server running in the frontend docker container not able to communicate with express API in the backend docker container in 2 separate files

I apologize if this is a long post.
I have 2 VSCode projects: a nuxt.js VERSION 2 frontend and a node.js express backend that acts as the API.
Each of them has a separate docker-compose file with its own nginx server and self generated SSL certificates that work on localhost
I am not able to connect with frontend with the backend to make API requests

Project Structure Frontend
docker
├── development
│   ├── nginx_server
│   │   └── Dockerfile
│   ├── nginx_server_certs
│   │   ├── Dockerfile
│   │   └── ...
│   ├── nuxt_server
│   │   └── Dockerfile
│   ├── docker-compose.yml
│   └── .env
└── production
    └── ...
pages
components
nuxt.config.js
package.json
...

Project Structure backend
docker
├── development
│   ├── nginx_server
│   │   └── Dockerfile
│   ├── nginx_server_certs
│   │   ├── Dockerfile
│   │   └── ...
│   ├── node_server
│   │   └── Dockerfile
│   ├── ...
│   ├── docker-compose.yml
│   └── .env
└── production
    └── ...
src
package.json
tsconfig.json
...

My nuxt server runs on port 31271 in the frontend docker-compose file and nginx runs on 80 for HTTP and 443 for HTTPS
Frontend docker-compose.yml
name: ch_ui_dev
services:
  ch_ui_dev_nginx:
    build:
      context: ../..
      dockerfile: ./docker/development/nginx_server/Dockerfile
    container_name: ch_ui_dev_nginx
    depends_on:
      ch_ui_dev_nuxt:
        condition: service_started
      ch_ui_dev_nginx_certs:
        condition: service_completed_successfully
    image: ch_ui_dev_nginx_image
    ports:
      - '80:80'
      - '443:443'
    restart: 'always'
    networks:
      - network
    volumes:
      - nginx_certs:/etc/nginx/nginx_certs

  ch_ui_dev_nginx_certs:
    build:
      context: ../..
      dockerfile: ./docker/development/nginx_server_certs/Dockerfile
    container_name: ch_ui_dev_nginx_certs
    env_file:
      - .env
    image: ch_ui_dev_nginx_certs_image
    networks:
      - network
    volumes:
      - nginx_certs:/home/nginx_certs/files

  ch_ui_dev_nuxt:
    build:
      context: ../..
      dockerfile: ./docker/development/nuxt_server/Dockerfile
    container_name: ch_ui_dev_nuxt
    env_file:
      - .env
    image: ch_ui_dev_nuxt_image
    networks:
      - network
    restart: 'always'
    ports:
      - '31271:31271'
    volumes:
      - nuxt_src:/home/node
      - node_modules:/home/node/node_modules

networks:
  network:
    external: true

volumes:
  nginx_certs:
    driver: local
  node_modules:
    driver: local
  nuxt_src:
    driver_opts:
      type: none
      device: /Users/vr/Desktop/code/ch/ui/
      o: bind


Frontend nginx container configuration for the nuxt server
pid                  /tmp/nginx.pid;
worker_processes     auto;
worker_rlimit_nofile 65535;

# Load modules
include              /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
    multi_accept       on;
    worker_connections 65535;
}

http {
    charset                utf-8;
    sendfile               on;
    tcp_nopush             on;
    tcp_nodelay            on;
    server_tokens          off;
    types_hash_max_size    2048;
    types_hash_bucket_size 64;
    client_max_body_size   16M;

    # MIME
    include                mime.types;
    default_type           application/octet-stream;

    # Logging
    access_log             off;
    error_log              /var/log/nginx/error.log error;

    # Limits
    limit_req_log_level    warn;
    limit_req_zone         $binary_remote_addr zone=login:10m rate=10r/m;

    # SSL
    ssl_session_timeout    1d;
    ssl_session_cache      shared:SSL:10m;
    ssl_session_tickets    off;

    # Diffie-Hellman parameter for DHE ciphersuites
    ssl_dhparam            /etc/nginx/nginx_certs/dhparam.pem;

    # Mozilla Intermediate configuration
    ssl_protocols          TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
    ssl_ciphers            ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384;

    # OCSP Stapling
    ssl_stapling           on;
    ssl_stapling_verify    on;
    resolver               1.1.1.1 1.0.0.1 [2606:4700:4700::1111] [2606:4700:4700::1001] 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4 [2001:4860:4860::8888] [2001:4860:4860::8844] 208.67.222.222 208.67.220.220 [2620:119:35::35] [2620:119:53::53] valid=60s;
    resolver_timeout       2s;

    # Connection header for WebSocket reverse proxy
    map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
        default upgrade;
        ""      close;
    }

    map $remote_addr $proxy_forwarded_elem {

        # IPv4 addresses can be sent as-is
        ~^[0-9.]+$        "for=$remote_addr";

        # IPv6 addresses need to be bracketed and quoted
        ~^[0-9A-Fa-f:.]+$ "for=\"[$remote_addr]\"";

        # Unix domain socket names cannot be represented in RFC 7239 syntax
        default           "for=unknown";
    }

    map $http_forwarded $proxy_add_forwarded {

        # If the incoming Forwarded header is syntactically valid, append to it
        "~^(,[ \\t]*)*([!#$%&'*+.^_`|~0-9A-Za-z-]+=([!#$%&'*+.^_`|~0-9A-Za-z-]+|\"([\\t \\x21\\x23-\\x5B\\x5D-\\x7E\\x80-\\xFF]|\\\\[\\t \\x21-\\x7E\\x80-\\xFF])*\"))?(;([!#$%&'*+.^_`|~0-9A-Za-z-]+=([!#$%&'*+.^_`|~0-9A-Za-z-]+|\"([\\t \\x21\\x23-\\x5B\\x5D-\\x7E\\x80-\\xFF]|\\\\[\\t \\x21-\\x7E\\x80-\\xFF])*\"))?)*([ \\t]*,([ \\t]*([!#$%&'*+.^_`|~0-9A-Za-z-]+=([!#$%&'*+.^_`|~0-9A-Za-z-]+|\"([\\t \\x21\\x23-\\x5B\\x5D-\\x7E\\x80-\\xFF]|\\\\[\\t \\x21-\\x7E\\x80-\\xFF])*\"))?(;([!#$%&'*+.^_`|~0-9A-Za-z-]+=([!#$%&'*+.^_`|~0-9A-Za-z-]+|\"([\\t \\x21\\x23-\\x5B\\x5D-\\x7E\\x80-\\xFF]|\\\\[\\t \\x21-\\x7E\\x80-\\xFF])*\"))?)*)?)*$" "$http_forwarded, $proxy_forwarded_elem";

        # Otherwise, replace it
        default "$proxy_forwarded_elem";
    }

    # Load configs
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}

# configuration file /etc/nginx/mime.types:

types {
    text/html                                        html htm shtml;
    text/css                                         css;
    text/xml                                         xml;
    image/gif                                        gif;
    image/jpeg                                       jpeg jpg;
    application/javascript                           js;
    application/atom+xml                             atom;
    application/rss+xml                              rss;
}

# configuration file /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:
server {
    listen       8080;
    server_name  localhost;

    #access_log  /var/log/nginx/host.access.log  main;

    location / {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }

    #error_page  404              /404.html;

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    #
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    # proxy the PHP scripts to Apache listening on 127.0.0.1:80
    #
    #location ~ \.php$ {
    #    proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1;
    #}

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    #
    #location ~ \.php$ {
    #    root           html;
    #    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
    #    fastcgi_index  index.php;
    #    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /scripts$fastcgi_script_name;
    #    include        fastcgi_params;
    #}

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    #location ~ /\.ht {
    #    deny  all;
    #}
}


# configuration file /etc/nginx/conf.d/example.local.conf:
server {
    listen              443 ssl http2;
    listen              [::]:443 ssl http2;
    server_name         www.example.local;

    # SSL
    ssl_certificate     /etc/nginx/nginx_certs/nginx-self-signed.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/nginx_certs/nginx-self-signed.key;

    # security
    include             nginxconfig.io/security.conf;

    # logging
    error_log           /var/log/nginx/error.log error;

    # reverse proxy
    location / {
        proxy_pass            http://ch_ui_dev_nuxt:31271/;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        include               nginxconfig.io/proxy.conf;
    }

    # additional config
    include nginxconfig.io/general.conf;
}

# non-www, subdomains redirect
server {
    listen              443 ssl http2;
    listen              [::]:443 ssl http2;
    server_name         .example.local;

    # SSL
    ssl_certificate     /etc/nginx/nginx_certs/nginx-self-signed.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/nginx_certs/nginx-self-signed.key;

    # logging
    error_log           /var/log/nginx/error.log error;
    return              301 https://www.example.local$request_uri;
}

# HTTP redirect
server {
    listen      80;
    listen      [::]:80;
    server_name .example.local;

    # logging
    error_log   /var/log/nginx/error.log error;
    return      301 https://www.example.local$request_uri;
}

# configuration file /etc/nginx/nginxconfig.io/security.conf:
# security headers
add_header X-XSS-Protection          "1; mode=block" always;
add_header X-Content-Type-Options    "nosniff" always;
add_header Referrer-Policy           "no-referrer-when-downgrade" always;
add_header Content-Security-Policy   "default-src 'self' http: https: ws: wss: data: blob: 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; frame-ancestors 'self';" always;
add_header Permissions-Policy        "interest-cohort=()" always;
add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload" always;

# . files
location ~ /\.(?!well-known) {
    deny all;
}

# security.txt
location /security.txt {
    return 301 /.well-known/security.txt;
}

location = /.well-known/security.txt {
    alias ~/security.txt;
}

# configuration file /etc/nginx/nginxconfig.io/proxy.conf:
proxy_http_version                 1.1;
proxy_cache_bypass                 $http_upgrade;

# Proxy SSL
proxy_ssl_server_name              on;

# Proxy headers
proxy_set_header Upgrade           $http_upgrade;
proxy_set_header Connection        $connection_upgrade;
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP         $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header Forwarded         $proxy_add_forwarded;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For   $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host  $host;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port  $server_port;

# Proxy timeouts
proxy_connect_timeout              60s;
proxy_send_timeout                 60s;
proxy_read_timeout                 60s;

# configuration file /etc/nginx/nginxconfig.io/general.conf:
# favicon.ico
location = /favicon.ico {
    log_not_found off;
}

# robots.txt
location = /robots.txt {
    log_not_found off;
}

# gzip
gzip            on;
gzip_vary       on;
gzip_proxied    any;
gzip_comp_level 6;
gzip_types      text/plain text/css text/xml application/json application/javascript application/rss+xml application/atom+xml image/svg+xml;

My node server runs on port 34273 in the backend docker-compose file and nginx runs here on 8080 for HTTP and 8443 for HTTPS
Backend docker-compose.yml
version: '3.9'
name: ch_api_dev
services:
  ch_api_dev_nginx:
    build:
      context: ../..
      dockerfile: ./docker/development/nginx_server/Dockerfile
    container_name: ch_api_dev_nginx
    depends_on:
      ch_api_dev_node:
        condition: service_started
      ch_api_dev_nginx_certs:
        condition: service_completed_successfully
    image: ch_api_dev_nginx_image
    ports:
      - '8080:8080'
      - '8443:8443'
    restart: 'always'
    networks:
      - network
    volumes:
      - nginx_certs:/etc/nginx/nginx_certs

  ch_api_dev_nginx_certs:
    build:
      context: ../..
      dockerfile: ./docker/development/nginx_server_certs/Dockerfile
    container_name: ch_api_dev_nginx_certs
    env_file:
      - .env
    image: ch_api_dev_nginx_certs_image
    networks:
      - network
    volumes:
      - nginx_certs:/home/nginx_certs/files

  ch_api_dev_node:
    build:
      context: ../..
      dockerfile: ./docker/development/node_server/Dockerfile
    container_name: ch_api_dev_node
    depends_on:
      ch_api_dev_redis:
        condition: service_healthy
      ch_api_dev_postgres_seeds:
        condition: service_completed_successfully
    env_file:
      - .env
    image: ch_api_dev_node_image
    networks:
      - network
    restart: 'always'
    ports:
      - '34273:34273'
    volumes:
      - node_src:/home/node
      - node_modules:/home/node/node_modules
      - postgres_certs:/certs/postgres
      - redis_certs:/certs/redis

  ch_api_dev_postgres:
    build:
      context: ../..
      dockerfile: ./docker/development/postgres_server/Dockerfile
    container_name: ch_api_dev_postgres
    depends_on:
      ch_api_dev_postgres_certs:
        condition: service_completed_successfully
    env_file:
      - .env
    healthcheck:
      test:
        [
          'CMD-SHELL',
          "pg_isready -d 'sslmode=verify-full sslrootcert=/certs/root.crt sslcert=/certs/psql.crt sslkey=/certs/psql.key host=ch_api_dev_postgres user=ch_api_user port=47293 dbname=ch_api_db'",
        ]
      interval: 5s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 3
      start_period: 10s
    image: ch_api_dev_postgres_image
    networks:
      - network
    ports:
      - '47293:47293'
    restart: 'always'
    volumes:
      - postgres_certs:/certs
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data

  ch_api_dev_postgres_certs:
    build:
      context: ../..
      dockerfile: ./docker/development/postgres_server_certs/Dockerfile
    container_name: ch_api_dev_postgres_certs
    env_file:
      - .env
    image: ch_api_dev_postgres_certs_image
    networks:
      - network
    volumes:
      - postgres_certs:/home/postgres_certs/files

  ch_api_dev_postgres_seeds:
    build:
      context: ../..
      dockerfile: ./docker/development/postgres_seeds/Dockerfile
    container_name: ch_api_dev_postgres_seeds
    depends_on:
      ch_api_dev_postgres:
        condition: service_healthy
    env_file:
      - .env
    image: ch_api_dev_postgres_seeds_image
    networks:
      - network
    volumes:
      - postgres_seeds_src:/home/node
      - postgres_seeds_node_modules:/home/node/node_modules
      - postgres_certs:/certs/postgres
      - redis_certs:/certs/redis

  ch_api_dev_redis:
    build:
      context: ../..
      dockerfile: ./docker/development/redis_server/Dockerfile
    container_name: ch_api_dev_redis
    depends_on:
      ch_api_dev_redis_certs:
        condition: service_completed_successfully
    env_file:
      - .env
    healthcheck:
      test:
        [
          'CMD-SHELL',
          'redis-cli --tls --cert /etc/ssl/certs/client.crt --key /etc/ssl/certs/client.key --cacert /etc/ssl/certs/ca.crt -p 41729 -a $REDIS_PASSWORD ping | grep PONG',
        ]
      interval: 5s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 3
      start_period: 10s
    image: ch_api_dev_redis_image
    networks:
      - network
    ports:
      - '41729:41729'
    restart: 'always'
    volumes:
      - redis_data:/data
      - redis_certs:/etc/ssl/certs

  ch_api_dev_redis_certs:
    build:
      context: ../..
      dockerfile: ./docker/development/redis_server_certs/Dockerfile
    container_name: ch_api_dev_redis_certs
    env_file:
      - .env
    image: ch_api_dev_redis_certs_image
    networks:
      - network
    volumes:
      - redis_certs:/home/redis_certs/files

networks:
  network:
    external: true

volumes:
  nginx_certs:
    driver: local
  node_modules:
    driver: local
  node_src:
    driver_opts:
      type: none
      device: /Users/vr/Desktop/code/ch/api/
      o: bind
  postgres_certs:
    driver: local
  postgres_data:
    driver: local
  postgres_seeds_node_modules:
    driver: local
  postgres_seeds_src:
    driver_opts:
      type: none
      device: /Users/vr/Desktop/code/ch/api/
      o: bind
  redis_certs:
    driver: local
  redis_data:
    driver: local


Backend Nginx container configuration file for the node.js server
pid                  /tmp/nginx.pid;
worker_processes     auto;
worker_rlimit_nofile 65535;

# Load modules
include              /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
    multi_accept       on;
    worker_connections 65535;
}

http {
    charset                utf-8;
    sendfile               on;
    tcp_nopush             on;
    tcp_nodelay            on;
    server_tokens          off;
    types_hash_max_size    2048;
    types_hash_bucket_size 64;
    client_max_body_size   16M;

    # MIME
    include                mime.types;
    default_type           application/octet-stream;

    # Logging
    access_log             off;
    error_log              /var/log/nginx/error.log error;

    # Limits
    limit_req_log_level    warn;
    limit_req_zone         $binary_remote_addr zone=login:10m rate=10r/m;

    # SSL
    ssl_session_timeout    1d;
    ssl_session_cache      shared:SSL:10m;
    ssl_session_tickets    off;

    # Diffie-Hellman parameter for DHE ciphersuites
    ssl_dhparam            /etc/nginx/nginx_certs/dhparam.pem;

    # Mozilla Intermediate configuration
    ssl_protocols          TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
    ssl_ciphers            ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384;

    # OCSP Stapling
    ssl_stapling           on;
    ssl_stapling_verify    on;
    resolver               1.1.1.1 1.0.0.1 [2606:4700:4700::1111] [2606:4700:4700::1001] 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4 [2001:4860:4860::8888] [2001:4860:4860::8844] 208.67.222.222 208.67.220.220 [2620:119:35::35] [2620:119:53::53] valid=60s;
    resolver_timeout       2s;

    # Connection header for WebSocket reverse proxy
    map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
        default upgrade;
        ""      close;
    }

    map $remote_addr $proxy_forwarded_elem {

        # IPv4 addresses can be sent as-is
        ~^[0-9.]+$        "for=$remote_addr";

        # IPv6 addresses need to be bracketed and quoted
        ~^[0-9A-Fa-f:.]+$ "for=\"[$remote_addr]\"";

        # Unix domain socket names cannot be represented in RFC 7239 syntax
        default           "for=unknown";
    }

    map $http_forwarded $proxy_add_forwarded {

        # If the incoming Forwarded header is syntactically valid, append to it
        "~^(,[ \\t]*)*([!#$%&'*+.^_`|~0-9A-Za-z-]+=([!#$%&'*+.^_`|~0-9A-Za-z-]+|\"([\\t \\x21\\x23-\\x5B\\x5D-\\x7E\\x80-\\xFF]|\\\\[\\t \\x21-\\x7E\\x80-\\xFF])*\"))?(;([!#$%&'*+.^_`|~0-9A-Za-z-]+=([!#$%&'*+.^_`|~0-9A-Za-z-]+|\"([\\t \\x21\\x23-\\x5B\\x5D-\\x7E\\x80-\\xFF]|\\\\[\\t \\x21-\\x7E\\x80-\\xFF])*\"))?)*([ \\t]*,([ \\t]*([!#$%&'*+.^_`|~0-9A-Za-z-]+=([!#$%&'*+.^_`|~0-9A-Za-z-]+|\"([\\t \\x21\\x23-\\x5B\\x5D-\\x7E\\x80-\\xFF]|\\\\[\\t \\x21-\\x7E\\x80-\\xFF])*\"))?(;([!#$%&'*+.^_`|~0-9A-Za-z-]+=([!#$%&'*+.^_`|~0-9A-Za-z-]+|\"([\\t \\x21\\x23-\\x5B\\x5D-\\x7E\\x80-\\xFF]|\\\\[\\t \\x21-\\x7E\\x80-\\xFF])*\"))?)*)?)*$" "$http_forwarded, $proxy_forwarded_elem";

        # Otherwise, replace it
        default "$proxy_forwarded_elem";
    }

    # Load configs
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}

# configuration file /etc/nginx/mime.types:

types {
    text/html                                        html htm shtml;
    text/css                                         css;
    text/xml                                         xml;
    image/gif                                        gif;
    image/jpeg                                       jpeg jpg;
    application/javascript                           js;
    application/atom+xml                             atom;
    application/rss+xml                              rss;
}

# configuration file /etc/nginx/conf.d/api.example.local.conf:
server {
    listen              8443 ssl http2;
    listen              [::]:8443 ssl http2;
    server_name         www.api.example.local;

    # SSL
    ssl_certificate     /etc/nginx/nginx_certs/nginx-self-signed.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/nginx_certs/nginx-self-signed.key;

    # security
    include             nginxconfig.io/security.conf;

    # logging
    error_log           /var/log/nginx/error.log error;

    # reverse proxy
    location / {
        proxy_pass            http://ch_api_dev_node:34273/;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        include               nginxconfig.io/proxy.conf;
    }

    # additional config
    include nginxconfig.io/general.conf;
}

# non-www, subdomains redirect
server {
    listen              8443 ssl http2;
    listen              [::]:8443 ssl http2;
    server_name         .api.example.local;

    # SSL
    ssl_certificate     /etc/nginx/nginx_certs/nginx-self-signed.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/nginx_certs/nginx-self-signed.key;

    # logging
    error_log           /var/log/nginx/error.log error;
    return              301 https://www.api.example.local$request_uri;
}

# HTTP redirect
server {
    listen      8080;
    listen      [::]:8080;
    server_name .api.example.local;

    # logging
    error_log   /var/log/nginx/error.log error;
    return      301 https://www.api.example.local$request_uri;
}

# configuration file /etc/nginx/nginxconfig.io/security.conf:
# security headers
add_header X-XSS-Protection          "1; mode=block" always;
add_header X-Content-Type-Options    "nosniff" always;
add_header Referrer-Policy           "no-referrer-when-downgrade" always;
add_header Content-Security-Policy   "default-src 'self' http: https: ws: wss: data: blob: 'unsafe-inline'; frame-ancestors 'self';" always;
add_header Permissions-Policy        "interest-cohort=()" always;
add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload" always;

# . files
location ~ /\.(?!well-known) {
    deny all;
}

# security.txt
location /security.txt {
    return 301 /.well-known/security.txt;
}

location = /.well-known/security.txt {
    alias ~/security.txt;
}

# configuration file /etc/nginx/nginxconfig.io/proxy.conf:
proxy_http_version                 1.1;
proxy_cache_bypass                 $http_upgrade;

# Proxy SSL
proxy_ssl_server_name              on;

# Proxy headers
proxy_set_header Upgrade           $http_upgrade;
proxy_set_header Connection        $connection_upgrade;
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP         $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header Forwarded         $proxy_add_forwarded;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For   $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host  $host;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port  $server_port;

# Proxy timeouts
proxy_connect_timeout              60s;
proxy_send_timeout                 60s;
proxy_read_timeout                 60s;

# configuration file /etc/nginx/nginxconfig.io/general.conf:
# favicon.ico
location = /favicon.ico {
    log_not_found off;
}

# robots.txt
location = /robots.txt {
    log_not_found off;
}

# gzip
gzip            on;
gzip_vary       on;
gzip_proxied    any;
gzip_comp_level 6;
gzip_types      text/plain text/css text/xml application/json application/javascript application/rss+xml application/atom+xml image/svg+xml;

# configuration file /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:
server {
    listen       8080;
    server_name  localhost;

    #access_log  /var/log/nginx/host.access.log  main;

    location / {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }

    #error_page  404              /404.html;

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    #
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    # proxy the PHP scripts to Apache listening on 127.0.0.1:80
    #
    #location ~ \.php$ {
    #    proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1;
    #}

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    #
    #location ~ \.php$ {
    #    root           html;
    #    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
    #    fastcgi_index  index.php;
    #    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /scripts$fastcgi_script_name;
    #    include        fastcgi_params;
    #}

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    #location ~ /\.ht {
    #    deny  all;
    #}
}

Keep in mind that both nginx containers are separate and are using different self generated certificates
On localhost my /etc/hosts file has this line inside
127.0.0.1       localhost api.example.local www.api.example.local example.local www.example.local

When I open my backend URL at https://www.api.example.local:8443/api/v1/... endpoint, it works perfectly in the browser and I am able to retrieve JSON data
When I open my frontend URL at https://example.local the page loads but has a 500 error on it. Any API request does not go through and has a CORS Failed Error
as shown here
I did add a CORS middleware on my express server
import { NODE_ENV } from 'common/constants';

export function getAllowedOrigins() {
  // https://github.com/expressjs/cors/issues/272#issuecomment-1186236472
  let allowedOrigins: string[] = [];
  if (NODE_ENV === 'development') {
    // will not work on development when run from docker development
    allowedOrigins = [
      'http://localhost:3000',
      'https://example.local',
      'https://api.example.local:8443',
    ];
  } else if (NODE_ENV === 'test') {
    allowedOrigins = ['http://localhost:3000'];
  } else if (NODE_ENV === 'production') {
    // will not work on production when run from localhost because we don't include localhost:3000
    allowedOrigins = ['https://www.somewebsite.com', 'https://somewebsite.com'];
  }
  return allowedOrigins;
}


3 questions

what URL do I need to add to make this CORS error go away
My axios baseURL in nuxt.js server takes values from some environment variables

nuxt.config.js
...
export default {
  axios: {
    baseURL: `${process.env.BACKEND_PROTOCOL}://${process.env.BACKEND_HOST}:${process.env.BACKEND_PORT}`,
    credentials: true,
  },
}
...

What values should I put for BACKEND_PROTOCOL, BACKEND_HOST and BAKCNED_PORT here?

If I have a websocket connection in my backend to push data, what should the URL again be because I am unable to connect currently

